# How could locking be acquired in case of an update statement

Tags: database, locking

Consider a very simple update statement in database:

**update ABC set colA=456, colB=1 where colB=0;**

Assume we are using innoDB.

Which of the two statements is correct:

1. A read lock will be acquired on colB for `where` clause and then an exclusive lock will be acquired while executing an update ?
2. Only exclusive lock will be applied because database is smart enough to know that we are going to do an `update`